# Understanding JavaScript super() invocations by following the ECMAScript specification

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2017

### Code

```
class Parent {
  constructor() {}
}

class Child extends Parent {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
}
```

### Background

As I was trying to understand exactly how `super()` invocations in class constructors work, I followed the following sequence of [ECMAScript](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0) operations:

1. [new Child()](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-new-operator) calls [ChildConstructor.[[Construct]]](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-ecmascript-function-objects-construct-argumentslist-newtarget)
2. `kind` is **derived** (earlier set in [14.5.15](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-class-definitions-runtime-semantics-evaluation)), so no new `this` value is bound
3. [OrdinaryCallEvaluateBody](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-ordinarycallevaluatebody) is called, which ends up evaluating the body of the `Child` class constructor method, where `super()` is the first statement
4. [super()](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-super-keyword-runtime-semantics-evaluation) calls [ParentConstructor.[[Construct]]](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-ecmascript-function-objects-construct-argumentslist-newtarget), which takes us back to *step 3*, just with `kind` as **base** this time
5. Since `kind` is now **base**, a new `this` binding is created and bound to the *Environment Record* of the new *function environment* created for the `Parent` constructor
6. The rest of `Parent` constructor's body executes, and once done control flows back to `Child.[[Construct]]` where execution continues from step 11
7. Finally, `Child.[[Construct]]` tries to return `envRec.GetThisBinding`

---

### Question

The *Environment Record* for the `Child` constructor, created in `step 6` of `Child.[[Construct]]`, has no `this` binding (`[[ThisBindingStatus]]` is **uninitialized**). Thus, when we try to do `envRec.GetThisBinding` in step 8, we should as far as I can tell, get a `ReferenceError` ([as specified here](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-function-environment-records-getthisbinding)).

What am I missing here? I can't seem to see why the `Child` constructor won't throw an error, and indeed if the `[[ThisValue]]` of the `Child` constructor is set at all.

Comment: I'm trying to find those lines in the specification, but all my searches failed. Are those literal quotes or are you paraphrasing? Could you link to the specific section you're asking about?

Comment: Thanks for looking at it, @Barmar . The steps above are a much condensed version of what actually happens. There are too many steps to list everything, but I have linked to the important algorithms at keys steps for ease of reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed a step in your [`super()`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-super-keyword-runtime-semantics-evaluation) link:

> 1. Let `newTarget` be `GetNewTarget()`.
> 2. Assert: `Type(newTarget)` is Object.
> 3. Let `func` be ? `GetSuperConstructor()`.
> 4. Let `argList` be `ArgumentListEvaluation` of `Arguments`.
> 5. `ReturnIfAbrupt(argList)`.
> 6. Let `result` be ? `Construct(func, argList, newTarget)`.
> 7. Let `thisER` be `GetThisEnvironment( )`.
> 8. Return ? `thisER.BindThisValue(result)`.

Step `6` calls `ParentConstructor.[[Construct]]` as you mentioned, but then step 8 will set the `this` binding in the `Child` constructor body to the constructed value, so when `envRec.GetThisBinding` runs at the end off `ChildConstructor.[[Construct]]`, the `this` binding will be there